# How to make NSLog work with Python's logging module when using PyObjC?

Tags: python, django, logging, pyobjc, nslog

I'm writing a Django-based webapp that imports a Cocoa framework via PyObjC.  The Cocoa framework has `NSLog()` littered all through it and while I can see them when running the Django server in non-daemon mode, as soon as I go to daemon I simply lose all this useful `NSLog()` output.

Is there any easy way to get NSLog stuff to bubble up into the Python `logging` module's world so it can be merged in with the log messages being emitted by the actual Python code?

Did a little Googling and it seems like you might have to redirect stderr and somehow suck it back into Python in order to achieve this, which would be kind of a bummer ...

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog) page, NSLog basically works like

```
fprintf(stderr, format_string, args ...);
```

so you do need to capture / redirect the standard error output. I wrote a [post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-treat-logger-like-output-stream.html) some time ago which might help for Python-only programs, but I would guess that the Cocoa code accesses the process-level file descriptor 2 (`stderr`) under the covers. So you'll need to do some low-level fiddling around with the process' `stderr`. Here's an example:

```
old_stderr = os.dup(sys.stderr.fileno()) # keep a copy
fd = os.open('path/to/mylog', os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY)
os.dup2(fd, sys.stderr.fileno())
# Now, stderr output, including NSLog output, should go to 'path/to/mylog'
...
os.dup2(old_stderr, sys.stderr.fileno())
#stderr restored to its old state
```

Once you have `fd`, you can create a file-like object out of it and pass it to `StreamHandler`, for example, as a means to merging the output from Python code and Cocoa code.

Comment: Thanks for the info Vinay - I suspected as much.  I'll implement it and then post my actual solution for merging it into the Python `logging` logs here once I have it working.

Comment: For what it's worth, my eventual solution to this was to actually stop using NSLog() and write my own logging macros based on http://borkware.com/rants/agentm/mlog/ that would use logging levels to correspond to logging.error, logging.debug etc from Python.  The messages buffer up and then a repeating timer in the Python merges buffered messages from objc and native Python by time and emits them to the actual log file.